# GetBoundingClientRect but relative to the entire document

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, d3.js

Is there a method for getting the *client rect* for an element relative to the document besides offset? `getBoundingClientRect()` gets the value relative to the client's browser.

I'm using `D3` and *jQuery's* `height()` nor `width()` are working (I've even tried doing it `window.load()`), but `offset()` is. Neither are javascripts .offset

```
return [$e.offset().top + $e.height()/2, $e.offset().left + $e.width()/2]
```

`$e.height()` and `$e.width()` both return `0`

It's an *SVG* element, I'm just using it to edit my *SVG*. It's much easier to load/handle SVG's with `D3`. The project is not data related, it's just a map.

Comment: you have $e.height().height/2 it should be $e.height()/2

Comment: Is this an SVG element, or an HTML element? What are you doing with D3?

Comment: Your post is unclear. What is working and what is not working? Are the elements visible (you cannot use .offset() on hidden elements)?

Answer (score 30):

Using `element.getBoundingClientRect()` by itself returns `top` and `left` values that are relative to the viewport, like you discovered. If you want them to be relative to the document (and not be affected by scroll position), you can add the scroll position using `window.scrollY` and `window.scrollX`, like so:

```
const rect = element.getBoundingClientRect()

rect.left                   // (relative to viewport)
rect.top                    // (relative to viewport)
rect.left + window.scrollX  // (relative to document)
rect.top + window.scrollY   // (relative to document)
```

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect).

Comment: *"For cross-browser compatibility, use `window.pageYOffset` instead of `window.scrollY`"* - [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollY#Notes)

Comment: I agree with @vsync's comment above, but it needs further explanation. Note that `window.scrollY` is, effectively, the standard. The alias, `window.pageYOffset` _is_ cross-browser-compatible, but that's because `window.scrollY` works in all browsers but it doesn't work in **IE** (it may work in **IE11**). If you're no longer catering to IE, you can safely use `window.scrollY`.

Answer (score 10):

Here's an ES6 method that returns all the same properties as `getBoundingClientRect()` but relative to the entire document.

```
const getOffsetRect = (el) =>

  let rect   = el.getBoundingClientRect();

  // add window scroll position to get the offset position
  let left   = rect.left   + window.scrollX;
  let top    = rect.top    + window.scrollY;
  let right  = rect.right  + window.scrollX;
  let bottom = rect.bottom + window.scrollY;

  // polyfill missing 'x' and 'y' rect properties not returned
  // from getBoundingClientRect() by older browsers
  let x = rect.x === undefined ? left : rect.x + window.scrollX;
  let y = rect.y === undefined ? top : rect.y + window.scrollY;

  // width and height are the same
  let width  = rect.width;
  let height = rect.height;

  return { left, top, right, bottom, x, y, width, height };
};
```

Note: it's also poly-filling the `x` and `y` props, that are not returned from getBoundingClientRect() by older browsers

Comment: Nice method! Especially the polyfill!